# Tensorflow scalar Summary to human-readable text

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to inspect all values for a scalar in my event file. I don't want the aggregate statistics as returned by

`tensorboard --inspect --event_file <summary_file> --tag <scalar_tag>`

I want all information sufficient for reconstructing the scalar graph (i.e. the unsummarized ordered (x,y) pairs).

How can I do this either with `tensorboard` or the TF Python API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`tf.train.summary_iterator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/summary_iterator), e.g.

```
my_pairs = []
for e in tf.train.summary_iterator(my_event_file_path):
    for v in e.summary.value:
        if v.tag == my_tag:
            my_pairs.append((e.step, v.simple_value))
```

You may find that parsing your event file is slower than you would like, depending on how much data you put in there.

Comment: Thank you! It works. I looked for something like this in `tf.summary` ... very interesting choice to put it in `tf.train`